# docker push to Bluemix problems

Tags: docker, push, containers, ibm-cloud

I am trying to push docker containers to Bluemix and am encountering problems.

1) Yesterday I was able to push 3 containers. However, all of them are still showing `Vulnerability Assessment Incomplete`.

2) Today, when I tried to push a new container, I am getting `Internal server error: 503 trying to push tag`

Looking through some previous posts suggest that there is some problem at the Bluemix end. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like an issue at Bluemix to me, so I suggest to contact support; https://console.ng.bluemix.net/?direct=classic/#/contactUs/cloudOEPaneId=contactUs

Comment: by pushing container - you mean creating a new container, or pushing a new image to bluemix registry?

Comment: sorry for not being clear, I was pushing a docker image to the Bluemix registry.

Answer (score 0):

Since yesterday you were able to push 3 images to the registry and now you are getting a 503 error doing the same, I suggest you to open a support request directly from your Bluemix console using the support/help widget: in this way you'll involve IBM Containers support team in checking and fix this issue. They will be able to perform in-depth investigation of your error.

Please provide org and space guids and some details on the image you used (for example the Dockerfile, if you have it).

You can retrieve org and space guids using CF CLI (when you already logged in):

```
cf org <orgname> --guid
cf space <spacename> --guid
```